# Should we provide both asynchronous and synchronous implementations of SmtpClient wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) article, we should not provide synchronous wrappers of asynchronous implementations.

We've abstracted the `System.Net.SmtpClient` behind an interface so that we can easily test code that sends emails.

Since `SmtpClient` actually has both asynchronous and synchronous implementations, should we expose both of these or just expect any consumer of our `ISmtpClient` interface just to `Wait` our asynchronous `SendAsync` method.

Not sure what the guidelines are here when it comes to building a general purpose library. In our case we know that we need to use both async and sync versions.

Comment: You can always supply wrapped EAP/APM Task based async operation via Extension Methods. Then in your api documentation tell the user he has the option of using them via referencing your extension dll

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your consumers need both asynchronous and synchronous versions and you can provide those then **you should**. **Don't** force you consumers to do *sync over async*, it hurts performance and could end in deadlocks.

You can see many examples of this in `.Net` libraries like [`SemaphoreSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`Wait/WaitAsync`) or [`TPL Dataflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (`Post/SendAsync`). Almost always when there's an async option there's also a sync option. The only case I can recall where there's only an async version is in `WinRT`, but that's because [they are discouraging long sync calls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/20/keeping-apps-fast-and-fluid-with-asynchrony-in-the-windows-runtime.aspx).

---

As Ned Stoyanov mentioned, Toub's article is more about wrappers, and not true sync/async operations.

Answer (score 4):

I think the article argues more about the case when your API only provides `async` implementations, in that case it is just as easy for the client to provide a "sync over async" implementation so no value is being added by you providing one. I think in the case when both are provided you should expose both.